# red black tree insert implementation - what is a sentinel?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I got this code from http://web.mit.edu/~emin/www.old/source_code/cpp_trees/index.html
and its constructor for a red black node is

```
RedBlackTree::RedBlackTree()
{
  nil = new RedBlackTreeNode;
  nil->left = nil->right = nil->parent = nil;
  nil->red = 0;
  nil->key = MIN_INT;
  nil->storedEntry = NULL;

  root = new RedBlackTreeNode;
  root->parent = root->left = root->right = nil;
  root->key = MAX_INT;
  root->red=0;
  root->storedEntry = NULL;  
}
```

What is nil and why is it initialized in the constructor? Can I just declare a nil node in my private data field and initialize it in my insert function?

Comment: `nil` is a leaf node. One way to look at a RB Tree is to see all leaves as `nil` nodes

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Answer (score 3):

It is basically a place holder.

From the codes README:
/*  A sentinel is used for root and for nil.  These sentinels are 
  created when RedBlackTreeCreate is caled.  root->left should always  point to the node which is the root of the tree.  nil points to a node which should always be black but has aribtrary children and   parent and no key or info.  The point of using these sentinels is so that the root and nil nodes do not require special cases in the code */

From wikipedia [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree)

1.A node is either red or black.

2.The root is black. (This rule is sometimes omitted. Since the root can always be changed from red to black, but not necessarily vice-versa, this rule has little effect on analysis.)

3.All leaves (NIL) are black. (All leaves are same color as the root.)

4.Every red node must have two black child nodes.

5.Every path from a given node to any of its descendant leaves contains the same number of black nodes.

Answer (score 2):

a sentinel is an empty node, it's used instead of nullptr, 
because it removes the need for special handling of all the 
corner-cases, ie last node, first node etc.